# python regex: don't allow a specific character to repeat

Tags: python, regex

I have a regex

```
^[a-z][a-z0-9\-]{6,10}[a-z0-9]$
```

Which matches the following rules:

- 8-12 characters in length
- first character is lowercase alpha
- last characters lowercase alpha or digit
- internal characters can contain a hyphen

it's re-used a lot in a module, always alongside some other rules and regexes

while writing out some unit tests, i noticed that it's always used in conjunction with another specific rule.

- hyphens may not repeat

i can't wrap my head around integrating that rule into this one.  i've tried a few dozen approaches with lookbehinds and lookaheads, but have had no luck on isolating to the specific character AND keeping the length requirement.

Comment: You could add another test to see that it doesn't match "--" like:

`and not "--" in somestring`

Comment: Don't try and put too much logic inside a regex. Just define a function that applies the first regex and then check for double hyphens afterwards.

Comment: That is how things are currently working. Unfortunately, someone inevitably invokes this regex instead of the combined function, and bad data gets through.  I've had to do a dozen cleanups.

Answer (score 7):

No repeating hyphen  `^[a-z](?:[a-z0-9]|-(?!-)){6,10}[a-z0-9]$`

Explained

```
 ^ [a-z] 
 (?:
      [a-z0-9]   # alnum
   |             # or
      - (?! - )  # hyphen if not followed by hyphen
 ){6,10}
 [a-z0-9] $
```

Comment: thanks a ton. i never thought of using the `|` like that! I kept trying to work with something like `[a-z0-9]+[a-z0-9\-]` and trying to apply limits around that.

Comment: @JonathanVanasco - No problem. Sometimes all you have to do is read out loud what a construct is. For classes, it's like a _or_ b _or_ c. The or is really alternations. So, you could always split them out into alternations without losing meaning. Once split out, the can be operated on independently (ie. qualified).